# Are SVGs with embedded tiff files possible?

Tags: pdf, svg, imagemagick, tiff, color-profile

Can I save SVG files with `<image>`'s that references to a TIFF (with embedded ICC profile) file?

The main problem:

- I have a SVG that is filled with PNG files (RGB)
- Now I need to convert this document to a printable PDF file (CMYK)
- PNG only supports RGB - So replace the PNG src with TIFF src?
- The PNGs have the same resolution as the TIFF files.

Or any other ideas to convert a RGB SVG to a CMYK PDF?

Comment: According to the [SVG spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/embedded.html#ImageElement) (I checked 1.1, 1.2 and 2.0) "conforming viewers" *"need to support at least PNG, JPEG and SVG"*. So it seems TIFF support would be dependent on the tool you use to convert to PDF, and isn't portable. The SVG format does allow ICC profiles, but the *"result of processing an ‘image’ is always a four-channel RGBA result"*, so it's a little unclear to me whether having source files in CMYK would actually help in producing CMYK output...

Comment: @haraldK, thanks for that! I think I will just batch process my TIFF files to High Quality JPEGs with embedded CMYK. I think this should be the easiest way.

Comment: At least worth a try. If it happens to work with TIFF as well, that would be a bonus.

Comment: I tried ImageMagicks `convert` - SVG with TIFF => PDF = TIFF images colors are distorted and colors are wrong too.